# Android file:/// similar path

Tags: android, path

I'm developing an Android app that is a virtual tour. I have a problem in that I can't use "file:///" to go to the assets. I am using Panotour to make the tours, so in old versions all works great in my app, but now in the new version it detects that i'm using "file:///" so the tour stops and it doesn't charge. I have already a version in iOS, and there is no problem because I dont use "file:///" in the path, so is there an alternative to "file:///"? I have to access files in assets and the SDcard, and handle the path for base url in my webview.

Comment: You might ask this question here: http://www.kolor.com/forum/

Comment: i have already ask in there thanks, but i want to keep my question in here because is more an android situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time trying diferents solutions, the only way i can found is, search for the index.js in the files of the tour and change "==file://?" for anything like "==fifi://?" and it is done, i can now use the tour 360 app in android, it works at 100% for me.

**sumary**:

inside panotour files of builded project -> index.js 
change

```
=="file://?
```

to

```
=="fifi://? //anything
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to parse the path, for example:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/path_to_file"); //replace path_to_file with correct path.
uri.getPath();
```

Comment: donsen't word, it's says E/Web Console: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined:105
 is like from file:///android_asset/foldername pass to /android_asset/foldername

Comment: i want to use it in a WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()